# How to Query through a list of documents and then update the field value in firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to change the name of every state that named boston in my collection of document in firestore how can I query through the list of documents in firestore then change the current state name to the new name with react native?

I tried this

```
export const Save = ({ NewName }) => {

  var db = firebase.firestore()

  var batch = db.batch();

  var sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "boston");
  var sfRe = db.collection("country").doc("SF");

     return () => {

        batch.update(sfDocRef, {"state": NewName})
        batch.update(sfRe, {"state": NewName})

        batch.commit()
  }
}
```

but got this error

> Function WriteBatch.update() requires its first argument to be a DocumentReference, but it was: a custom query object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of facts, `sfDocRef` is not a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), but a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query).

You have to execute the query with the asynchronous [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) method and for each document returned by this query, add it to the batch. The following piece of code would do the trick:

```
var batch = db.batch();

var sfRe = db.collection("country").doc("SF");

var sfDocQuery = db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "boston");

sfDocQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        batch.update(doc.ref, { "state": NewName });
    });

    //......
    batch.update(sfRe, {"state": NewName});  //This one will work, since sfRe is a DocumentReference
    //......


    return batch.commit()

})
.then(() => {

    //The commit() method is asynchronous and returns a Promise

    //return for your Save function

})
```